# Would an asynchronous interrupt context write to the page table in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, virtual-memory, interrupt

Specifically, in the Linux kernel, is it possible that the page table (level3_kernel_pgt) can be overwritten when an asynchronous interrupt context happens (Local timer interrupts).
I've been seeing this behaviour. I'm not sure what's going on in the background. Or maybe if my tool is wrong.

Comment: What is LOC (edit question)?

Comment: Short for Local timer interrupts. Plz try $ cat /proc/interrupts and then you will see.

Comment: Yes. I was never going to find that: Read question, `find /proc -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i loc`, oh here it is. Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

A VM page is just a table in memory, this page of memory is not accessible from user-space. However all memory is accessible from kernel space.

So yes it is possible. Are all of your pointers valid?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Quick question what do you mean by "Are all of your pointers valid"?

Comment: Agree. All memory is accessible from kernel space. But specifically, I wanna know if an asynchronous interrupt context calling convention may write a higher-level page table such as level3_kernel_pgt. Or what exactly happens when an asynchronous interrupt e.g. how to switch to an interrupt context?

Comment: I don't we any thing specific in an interrupt service routine, that will write to the page that has the VM tables (or any where else that it should not). However I don't know what the memory context is: Will it be that of the interrupted code?, do you need to adjust it? Is it adjusted for you by existing kernel code?

Comment: My asking about stray pointers, is just a suggestion as to why memory may be written over.